# Can't find the GoToStateAction Behaviour in Blend 2017

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, blend, visualstatemanager

I am trying to use Blend 2017 to do a simple collapse/expand animation for a search panel. I created two states Collapsed and Expanded visual states and recorded the required movement. The problem now is that i can not find the GoStateAction behaviour to control the different visual states. I searched the internet but no clue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just installed the Nuget package for "Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend". For some reason Blend 2017 SDK do not install with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, none of the many NuGet packages do work, instead, here's the proper way:

**Install Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET using Visual Studio Installer:**

[image]

**Alternatively, the *Assets* window in Blend will offer to do it:**

(not visible here since it's already done, but you can see that everything is here)

[image]

And no more funny surprises like `Interaction.Behaviors` works but not the behaviors inside it, or that it has been built with an older SDK version :)